# Logarithmic equations (single correct)

Tags: logarithms

can you help me solve this:

> Find the product of all $x$ satisfying: $$x^{\log_{10}(x)}=x\left(100+2^{\sqrt{\log_2(3)}}-3^{\sqrt{\log_3(2)}}\right)$$
>
> > $$\text{(a) 0.1 (b) 1 (c) 10 (d) 100}$$

Comment: the equation is not so clear to read

Comment: is it $$x^{\log_{10} x}=\left(100+2^{\sqrt{\log_2 3}}-3^{\sqrt{\log_3 2}}\right)x$$?

Comment: are you sure it is (c)?

Comment: i would say $x=100$

Comment: Yes its Is c that is 10

Comment: if @Dr.SonnhardGraubner wrote the question good i am pretty sure that the answers are $0.1$ and $100$, please check the question again

Comment: The answer is 10 that is given with the question but how??

Comment: @Pearly whoever wrote the question made a mistake in the answer

Comment: What do you get the answer@Holo

Comment: i posted the answer with the way, look at it

Comment: also, you can easily check that $x=10$ is wrong by plugging in $x=10$ to the equation, you will get $10=1000$, which is clearly false

Comment: @Pearly excuse me for seeing something wrong: $x$ is indeed equal $0.1,100$ but the question is what is the product of all the $x$'s, so it is $100\cdot 0.1$ hence it is $10$. Sorry for misleading, (c) is the current answer, I thought the question is just to find $x$

Comment: Finally ...thank you ssoo much

Answer (score 2):

if $x^{\log_{10} x}=\left(100+2^{\sqrt{\log_2 3}}-3^{\sqrt{\log_3 2}}\right)x$ is really the question

there are 2 answers: $x=\begin{cases}0.1\\100\end{cases}$

---

start with that: $$2^{\sqrt{\log_2 3}}={(2^{\log_2 3})}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2 3}}}=3^\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2 3}}=3^{\sqrt{\log_3 2}}$$

so we left with$$100x=x^{\log_{10} x}$$take log base 10 of both sides to get$$\log_{10}(100x)=\log_{10}(x^{\log_{10} x})$$we will use some log identities:$$\text{left hand side:}\log_{10}(100x)=\log_{10}(x)+\log_{10}(100)=\log_{10}(x)+2\\\text{right hand side:}\log_{10}(x^{\log_{10} x})=\log_{10}(x)\log_{10}(x)=\log_{10}(x)^2$$

so we get $$\log_{10}(x)+2=\log_{10}(x)^2$$from this we get$$\log_{10}(x)=\begin{cases}-1\\2\end{cases}$$solve for this:$$\begin{cases}\log_{10}(x)=-1\implies x=\frac{1}{10}\\\log_{10}(x)=2\implies x=100\end{cases}$$

---

## edit

apparently i misread the question:

i thought you just need to find $x$, but you need to find the product of all the possible $x$'s, therefore the answer is $0.1\cdot 100=10$, so it is (c)

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: if it answer your question you should accept this answer

Comment: @Rohan i misread it, thank you for point it out for me

Comment: Computing the roots is not necessary, please see my comment to @Charge's answer. (And yes, answering such questions with zero context by a repeating offender is not... necessary either.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $2^\sqrt{\log_2 3} = 3^\sqrt{\log_3 2}$, the given equation simplifies to $x^{\log_{10} x} = 100x$. Taking the log of both sides, gives the quadratic equation in $\log_{10} x$ $$ (\log_{10}x)^2 - \log_{10} x - 2 =0$$, from which the sum of solutions can be read off as $\Sigma \log x_* =1 \Rightarrow \Pi x_* = 10$.

Comment: ...Hence the simplification you started with, is not even necessary. :-) That is, the same conclusion holds if $$100+2^{\sqrt{\log_2(3)}}-3^{\sqrt{\log_3(2)}}=100$$ is replaced by anything greater than $$10^{-1/4}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- $$2^{\sqrt{\log_2 3}} = 3^{\sqrt{\log_3 2}}$$
- If $\log_{10}x = r$, the equation can be written as: $$x^{\log_{10} x} = x^ r = (10^r)^r = 100x = 100(10^r)\implies r = \, ?$$

  ---

**EDIT:**

Solving the equation will give you: $r^2-r-2=0 \implies r = -1, 2 \implies x = 0.1, 100$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a multiple choice question you can save time by plugging each value in.

As $0.1=10^{-1}, 1 = 10^0, 10=10^1, 100=10^2$ $$\text{LHS}_{0.1}=0.1^{\log_{10}(0.1)}=0.1^{-1}=10,$$ $$\text{LHS}_1=1^{\log_{10}(1)}=1^{0}=1,$$$$\text{LHS}_{10}=10^{\log_{10}(10)}=10^{1}=10 \quad \text{and}$$  $$\text{LHS}_{100}=100^{\log_{10}(100)}=100^{2}=10000.$$ Also, $2^{\sqrt{\log_2(3)}}=3^{\sqrt{\log_3(2)}}$ so $\text{RHS}=x(100+0)=100x$. Similarly,
$$\text{RHS}_{0.1}=100(0.1)=10,$$ $$\text{RHS}_1=100(1)=100,$$$$\text{RHS}_{10}=100(10)=1000 \quad \text{and}$$  $$\text{RHS}_{100}=100(100)=10000.$$ Comparing gives the correct choices as $a)$ and $c)$.

Answer (score 0):

The last two terms are equal and cancel out (take the logarithm of both).

The we can try all four items:

$$0.1^{\log_{10}0.1}=0.1^{-1}=10=0.1\cdot100$$

$$1^{\log_{10}1}=1^0=1\ne1\cdot100$$
$$10^{\log_{10}10}=10^1=10\ne10\cdot100$$
$$100^{\log_{10}100}=100^2=10000=100\cdot100$$