# An interesting logarithms question

Tags: logarithms

> Product of all solutions of $x^{\log_{10}x}=\left(100+2^{\sqrt{\log_23}}-3\sqrt{\log_32}\right)x$

I tried solving this JEE Main level question, but I couldn't get an answer despite some steps.
I did use the formula $a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use MathJax on the assumption that, when the original source writes $\log_{a^b}$, it means $\log_ab$.

Comment: Have a look at [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577795/42969

Comment: It should rather be $3^\color{red}{\sqrt{\log_3 2}}$ there.

Answer (score 1):

That nasty constant term is just there to confuse you. Its value has no bearing on the result.

Take $\log_{10}$ of both sides to get
$$
(\log_{10} x)^2 = \log_{10} x + \log_{10}\left(100+2^{\sqrt{\log_{2} 3}}-3\sqrt{\log_3 2}\right)
$$

This is a quadratic equation, and thus has two solutions. By Vieta's formulas, their sum is $1$. Thus $\log_{10} x_1 + \log_{10} x_2 = 1$, and so $x_1x_2 = 10$.